# LED uniform light spread

Tags: led-strip

I am using an LED in my project. I need to provide uniform intensity or uniform spread of light using this LED in a particular area(Small region). Please tell some techniques for this. I have read about the use of plain glass with some chemical coating and place in front of the LED. Anybody knows about these? Please help me to find an appropriate technique.

Comment: You will get much better answers if you explain the problem you are trying to solve. "Small region?" Why not give dimensions? What is the distance of illumination? Front-light / back-light? Are you restricted with choice of LED? Are you restricted with number of LEDs? Get the idea?

Comment: yes. I am restricted with choice of LED and also number. I need only one LED to illuminate my sample space. Length x width x height : 5cm x 4cm x 5cm. Sample (rectangular shape) placed inside this unit

Comment: Search "LED lens".

Comment: "_I am restricted with choice of LED and also number._" More vagueness. What is the restriction? What is the number? Put all the information **in your question** not sprinkled through the comments. You haven't answered some of the questions such as distance of illumination, etc.

Comment: Small region means the dimensions are length x width x height : 5cm x 5cm x 3cm(rectangular box). Sample is placed at the bottom centre of the box and  led is placed 2.7cm away from my sample at the height of 1.5cm. Currently LED is not providing uniform light.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LED uniform lighting](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/264565/led-uniform-lighting)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about "frosted glass" or a diffuser. You can reflect the LED light off of a white, matte surface in order achieve diffusion. You can use holographic diffusers (efficient, generally) or ground glass or use hydrofluoric acid to "frost" the glass surface. I've even used waxed paper in a pinch (needed a quick diffuser for a fiber optic connection.)

It's impossible to say what the appropriate technique in your case is, though. Not without a lot more information from you. And even then?

But there are some of the techniques.

(You want the opposite of specular reflection, instead looking for a perfect Lambertian distribution of reflected light where the surface brightness looks about the same from any angle.)

---

I don't understand how 'uniformly' you have to get, but to take one LED output and to spread it out uniformly over an area will require some kind of a diffuser. One of the problems with diffusers is that they tend to disperse the light everywhere (by definition) and the intensity in some specific target area will integrate to a smaller value than before. But that is something that comes with the territory. (Holographic diffusers help here.)

Some LEDs come with a milky epoxy to help out. And you could consider modifying the LED itself, by sanding it or otherwise attempting to make it disperse the light differently.

What have you tried already and why is a diffuser out of the question?

Comment: Purpose is I want to illuminate my test strip uniformly. Any other techniques?

Comment: I am restricted with choice of LED and also number. I need only one LED to illuminate my sample space. Length x width x height : 5cm x 4cm x 5cm. Sample (rectangular shape) placed inside this unit

Comment: @Aradh Added a comment at the end, above.

Comment: Using a white paper strip 45° "mirror" is better than anything you can achieve with translucent glass. Of course, efficiency is worse.

Comment: @Janka Yeah. I mentioned reflection off of a white matte surface in my response, at the outset. I really don't know why there is a problem with that.